# Are computers deployed with a list of precomputed prime numbers

Tags: security, http, ssl, server, primes

With my understanding of public key encryption, a server generates a public key from the product of two large prime numbers, *`p`* and *`q`*, to produce *`n`*.

*`n`* is then sent to the client that wishes to securely connect to the server.

The client picks a random number *`x`* and computes *`x^3 modulo n`* and passes this back to the server.

The server then calculates *`x`* from using *`p`* and *`q`* and then *`x`* is used as the private key to encrypt all traffic and both client and server know this without it ever being exposed.

---

**Question**

For each client that wants to connect to the server, the server needs to create a public key for each connection. On a busy server this would require the generation of many *`p`*'s and *`q`*'s.

Whilst computers are fast, if both *`p`* and *`q`* are large numbers within the range of `2^1024` determining whether these numbers are prime would take a lot of effort, and repeated effort if lots of connections are made to the server (thinking Google, Facebook etc.).

Also if the the random picking of *`p`* or *`q`* turn out to be non-prime, then the server will need to pick another random number and determine whether that number is prime. This looks like there might be quite a lot of wasted computational time.

So rather than the server having to compute two random primes, for each connection, can/does the server pick from a list of pre-computed primes that are installed on the server ? If so, can we trust these prime numbers are actually prime, and, picked randomly ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com. That said, generating large primes is not nearly as expensive as you likely think. Generating a known prime is much cheaper than determining if a totally random number happens to be prime. To get you started, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Large_primes (which is very brief, but gives you some links; see particularly Mersenne primes).

Comment: I figured this had been answered on crypto.se already. Here you go: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-can-i-generate-large-prime-numbers-for-rsa

Comment: @MrDeveloper You misunderstand PKI, the server does not create a new public key for each client and connection.

Comment: Thanks @zaph. I did overlook the elephant in the question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand PKI, the server does not create a new public key for each client and connection.

Furthermore WRT creating RSA primes see the comments to the question by Rob Napier:

> "generating large primes is not nearly as expensive as you likely think."
>   and his link generating large prime numbers for RSA.